# Is InfoPath right for this purpose?

Tags: infopath

I'm currently looking for a way to make a dynamic checklist-type document for my job to be used for software upgrades. Right now, we have a generic Word checklist that has all the steps for upgrading a client's software, but due to its nature, not all steps apply to each client, and to list all possible options would make it difficult to navigate and difficult to use, which goes against its purpose.

What I'm looking for is a way to input information (checkboxes, drop-downs, and text fields), and based on that information, produce a list of tasks in some format that is user-readable. For example, if I check one box to indicate that they have a certain feature installed, then add 3 items to the task list.

Is InfoPath the right tool for the job, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I'd say InfoPath is a very good choice for your project. My first thought would be to work in two different views. The first view would be for your people to input the information about what features are installed (there can be hidden content that only shows if certain answers are given, making it less unwieldy than your Word form). Then I'd have another view designed for printing out and giving to the client, containing only the task list info derived from the data in the first view. Bark away!